# how to hide a text entry in the print preview c#

Tags: c#

There is no error showing. My selection is not working, I need to hide a specific field. If the field is empty the title of that field should be hidden. 
I am using a `printpreviewdialog` to preview the details.
my code:

```
 private void DVPrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        //e.Graphics.DrawString("NAME          : " + dgvItem.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 400));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("WEIGHT      : " + txtGemWeight.Text + " Cts", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 440));

        //string txtSpecification = false;

        if (txtSpecification.Text == null)
        {
            txtSpecification.Visible= false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("SPECIFICATION   : " + txtSpecification.Text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 480));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(txtSpecification.Text == null)
```

change it to

```
if(txtSpecification.Text == "")
```

because text by default value is not null.

Comment: Can you check out, what is the value of `default(string)`?

Comment: @Slava The default of a string value is just "" which is not null. For reasons, idk.